# Which is the last release of quickfix that support Java 7?

Tags: quickfixj

The last version de QuickFix need Java 8, but I can't find info about which is the last for JDK 7, could you help me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [QFJ 2.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/wiki/QFJ-2.0.0-release-notes) they started using the Java 8 Date/Time API in that release, and it is mentioned that "You need at least Java 8 to run QuickFIX/J". The major version was bumped because of this breaking change.

That means that the latest QuickFIX/J version supporting Java 7 should be the [1.6.4 release](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/releases/tag/QFJ_RELEASE_1_6_4).